# Thevenin Equivalent of this mesh

Tags: dc, thevenin, analysis, superposition

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAfSef.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have to calculate the resistancy value Rx, when the equivalent thevenin voltage is applied and generates a current of 2 Amperes on it. 
Im having some troubles with this. I know by superposition theorem that R1 and R4 get shortcircuited whileworking with each voltage source separately, and resistors parallel with a voltage source can be dismissed for calculations. 
So, I consider R3= 3 Ohms as the Thevenin Resistency. Complications arise calculating Thevenin Voltage using superposition theorem. ¿Should I calculate partial voltages on R3, and sum its values?

Comment: Have you tried to use KCL?

Comment: Which nodes are the output nodes?

Comment: The output nodes are the nodes of Rx

Answer (score 1):

A homework, I think. So, no full solutions, but some guidance:

First: V1 and V2 are ideal voltage sources, they have 50 and 100 volts regardless the currents. Thus R1 and R4 have no effect to the voltages and currents in Rx and R3. There are 50V between the left ends of Rx and R3, 100V between the right ends of Rx and R3.

The Thevenin equivalent voltage Et seen by Rx is the voltage over Rx when we set Rx=infinite (=open circuit). The the Thevenin equivalent resistance Rt = Et/I when I is the current of Rx after setting Rx=0.

Stop. You must go with these.

Comment: "*I have to calculate the resistancy value Rx*", dead giveaway that it is homework.